# How to make an order when the basket is at least $ 10 for OpenCart 3.0.2.0?

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I am using OpenCart version 3.0.2.0. My problem is that if the basket amount created by the customer reaches $10 and passes, how do I make it accepted as an order.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read *[how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)* to let us help you better 

Answer (score 1):

Using standard tools, you can setting a minimum price for Shipping and Payment methods. If you have a Shipping or Payment methods with minimum price of 10$ - the smaller total checkout will be impossible, because. Note. Not every Shipping or Payment has these settings.

More complex way:

**catalog/controller/checkout/checkout.php**

find (line 4-7)

```
        // Validate cart has products and has stock.
        if ((!$this->cart->hasProducts() && empty($this->session->data['vouchers'])) || (!$this->cart->hasStock() && !$this->config->get('config_stock_checkout'))) {
            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
        }
```

add below

```
if ($this->cart->getSubtotal() < 10) {
    $this->session->data['error'] = 'Your warning message';
    $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
}
```